# Storyboard and memory management

Tags: objective-c, memory, storyboard

I am using storyboard and i stumbled upon something i have not been able to grasp.

I am putting up my view controller programmatically with `performSegueWithIdentifier:`.

It works like a charm, but what i noticed was that every single time i do this, i create a new instance of that viewController, and so, i have memory that keeps piling up. When i simulate a memory warning, i see that for each time i have been calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:`

i have a new instance of the view controller, and it NEVER gets deallocated. So memory just piles up and i cannot release it, which eventually causes a crash.

I just go to the view controller like this:

```
// If sales are registered, go to view
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"previousSaleSegue" sender:self];
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: show us your codes in `performSegueWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: done, but there is nothing special to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be stacking view controllers on top of each other instead of returning to a previous one. Assuming you are using a navigation controller, you'll be doing this:

```
A --push--> B --finished! Push---> New A ---Push---> B ---Finished! push--->A ...
```

What you should be doing is:

```
A --push--> B --finished! Pop -
^-----------------------------/
```

You're using modal segues by your comments, in this case you need to add an action to your return button to dismiss the view controller (returning to the previous one) instead of presenting another instance. The principle is the same. You'd use

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: i am not using Navigation Controller, but maybe the concept is the same? 
PerformSegueWithIdentifier creates a new instance and throws up on the stack. Then if i have to return to the previous segue i would have to "dismissViewController" to remove it? is that how it is to be understood? :)

Comment: How do you "return to previous segue"?

Comment: Using storyboard segues, directly dragging it from a return button with style modal

Comment: Yes, use dismissViewController.

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain that viewcontroller instance does not get deallocated it must be because you keep reference to it somewhere (it could be a cycle on the controller itself).

Comment: I really can't see how i am referencing it. i do not at any point create a manual extra reference to a view controller.